# assigning an array value to a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I came across a problem which I did manage to solve but I honestly do not understand how this works.

```
var array = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest = 0;
//My code
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > largest) {
        largest = array[i];
    }
}

console.log(largest);
```

How does my array assign a value to my variable within the if statement?

Why does this version not work?

```
array[i] = largest;
```

I'm very new to programming and I believe that understanding fundamental things as small as this can help many beginners become competent programmers.

Comment: Aside from books a great online resource is the brilliant MDN. [**MDN - Learn JavaScript**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript), [**MDN - JavaScript Documentation Index**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript) There you find documentation and code examples on anything from arrays to if statements to closures. Reaching from the most simple to the more complex. Hope this resource helps you in achieving your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(array[i] > largest) {
           largest = array[i];
        }
```

`array[i]` is `3` and `largest` is `0` then if condition passes and

```
largest = array[i];
```

assign value right to left
now the `largest` value is `3`.

so next cycle `array[i]` is `6` so next `6 > 3` true , it will again change the `largest to 6`.

like it will give you largest number.

Comment: So when I use an = sign its known as assignment and values are assigned from the right side to left side. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaking the assignment statement in programming with the equality statement in mathematics.

[Assignment vs Equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Assignment_versus_equality)

In your code, when you say largest = array[i] you are assigning to the variable 'largest' the value of the element on the ith position of the array. Notice here that the array is not changing any of its values in this assignment.

On the other hand,  array[i] = largest would try to assign to the ith position on the array the present value of the variable 'largest'.

Comment: woooooooow that was quick thank you, but maybe I am being dumb here but I still don't understand.  I know assignment is not the same as equality from maths. Really frustrating maybe I need to sleep on it? I don't even know what to ask to clarify that I don't understand :(

Answer (score 1):

This code is trying to calculate the largest value in an array of values..

Doing

```
array[i] = largest;
```

would modify the input itself which is undesired... you need to find the largest value from the given input.. and not modify the given input location to some largest value.

That is why

```
largest = array[i]
```

is correct.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a value to a variable, the variable has to be on the left of the assignment operator (the equals sign "=").

This way has the variable on the left:

```
largest = array[i];
```

It puts the *array[i]* value into the *largest* variable, and so it works.

This way is backwards:

```
array[i] = largest;
```

It puts the *largest* value into the *array[i]* element, and your array ends up with a bunch of zeros in it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but i've this issue today and want to help others developers with proper source of knowledge, comming directly from Kyle Simpson.

> [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS)

Operator assignment has his own way to work. It calculate the statement of the right "=" to later asign it, to the left. This is very important to know how does it work.

Example:

```
var array = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest = 0;
//My code
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > largest) {
        largest = array[i];
    }
}

console.log(largest);
```

Here, `largest = array[i];`

JS, is **calculate** the statement of the **right** and **assing to the left**

So have fun with the book and play.